# Code signing fail for the framework in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xamarin.ios, frameworks, code-signing

I am building my Xamarin.iOS project as an Ad-hoc. I have created a .dll using my unity application and added it to my Xamarin.iOS project. I was able to run my app on the device using my developer certificate. Once I build it using distribution as ad-hoc I am getting following error.

> Failed to codesign
> 'bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/MyXamarinApp.app//Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework':
> /Users/me/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyXamarinApp.iOS/268eeadf1f5c986de40b9d36628cd/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/MyXamarinApp.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework:
> errSecInternalComponent

VS version is 16.11.3

Xcode version is  12.5.1

Do I need to build the unity app also using the same bundle ID that I use for my Xamarin.iOS project?

What is the reason for this and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, Ad Hoc Distribution allows developers to beta test apps on a wide range of devices when iTunes connect is not an option.

you need to create an IPA and distribute it using TestFlight or iTunes.

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=macos).

Here are the details about [TestFlight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/testflight?tabs=macos).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My problem is how to create the IPA when it is giving this error?

Comment: You can check that the certificate and profiles match. Check the first link I sent you, check the Create a Distribution Certificate step above and see if there is an error on one of the steps.